# wp_dropdown_pages (Show pages only with custom taxonomy)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to echo the pages only with the custom taxonomy, but now i have drop down all pages what i have in custom post type.

```
<?php                                                       
 $post_type_object = get_post_type_object('property');                     
     if ($post) {
$parent_properties_dropdown_args =  array(
    'post_type'        => 'property',
    'property_status'  => 'condominium-villas-project', // <<-- Here is the (property_status - is the custom taxonomy and condominium-villas-project is the custom taxonomy tag)
    'selected'         => $prop_data->post_parent,
    'name'             => 'parent_id',
    'show_option_none'  => __('Not selected'),
    'echo'             => 0,);                    

                    $parent_properties_dropdown = wp_dropdown_pages($parent_properties_dropdown_args);

if (! empty($parent_properties_dropdown)) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-option parent-field-wrapper">
        <label for=""></label>
        <?php echo $parent_properties_dropdown; ?>
    </div>
    <?php

} }
```

But im anyway get all pages in custom post type 'property'. i need only 'property' with the taxonomy to show.

example:
now ->
- Property 1 - 'property_status' 'rent'
- Property 2 - 'property_status' 'sale'
- property 3 - 'property_status' 'condominium-villas-project'

i want to get only
- property 3 - 'property_status' 'condominium-villas-project'

Comment: What is `$prop_data`?  Should that not be `$post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what I think is your exact code *(I am still confused by your use of `$prop_data`)* you could use the following code to get what *(I think)* you are looking for. Add the code to your theme's `function.php` file, a `.php` file it requires, or one of the `.php` files of a plugin you might implement:

```
<?php

class wpse_51782342 {
    static function on_load() {
        add_filter( 'get_pages',  [ __CLASS__, '_get_pages' ], 10, 2 );
    }

    static function _get_pages( $pages, $args ) {
        if ( isset( $args[ 'property_status' ] ) ) {
            $pages = get_posts(array(
                'post_type'       => 'property',
                'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                'property_status' => $args[ 'property_status' ],
                'include'         => wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' ),
            ));
        }
        return $pages;
    }
}
wpse_51782342::on_load();
```

The `'get_pages'` filter hook runs at the end of `get_pages()` which is called by `wp_dropdown_pages()`. In that hook the code looks for the argument you passed named `'property_status'` to decide if it should modify behavior.  *This is an important technique because it ensures that the same args will always return the same results and are not dependent on something like the current post ID or URL. Following this principle will usually reduce the number of bugs you have to fix in your project.*

If the argument `'property_status'` is found the `$args` array the code uses its value to call `get_posts()` to return a list of posts that have been assigned the value of `property_status` that you passed to `wp_dropdown_pages()`.

Finally the code limits the `get_posts()` query to the `$post->ID`s from `$pages` found by the query already run by `wp_dropdown_pages()`.  This should result in a dropdown showing just the pages you prefer.

And for reference, here is the code in `single.php` to test out the above code, after I entered examples for property and property status, of course.

```
wp_dropdown_pages(array(
    'post_type'        => 'property',
    'property_status'  => 'condominium-villas-project',
    'selected'         => $post->ID,
    'name'             => 'ID',
    'show_option_none'  => __('Not selected'),
    'echo'             => 1,
));
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for a help

Comment: @Ruslan great!. If this is a good answer, can you give it an upvote too? Thanks/

Comment: :) When i finish i will do it, sure ) I'm try to add you code  to works )))

Comment: Totaly done, works perfectly. I'm just add your 1st park of the code before the im use wp_dropdown_pages and then it works. Now in drop down i saw only pages with the 'property_status'  => 'condominium-villas-project'. Thanks a lot for a help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter `wp_dropdown_pages()` with custom taxonomy. You can use normal WordPress query like below.

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'property_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'condominium-villas-project',
        )
    ),
) );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
?>
<div class="form-option parent-field-wrapper">
    <label for=""></label>
    <select name='parent_id' id='parent_id'>
        <option value="">Not selected</option>
<?php
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
?>
        <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```